# is Hash(password + salt) Fine

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt, bcrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Assuming salt is s random, high entropy, long string, and hash is `sha512` or `bcrypt`, 
**why** is `hash(password + perUserSalt)` considered not enough?

This question originated after reading the PHP's new [password hashing API RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) in which the author states that

> Hash(password + salt) = it's not fine

Comment: I've heard similar statements so I've always used `hmac_hash()`. Don't know which is better to be honest :S

Comment: The question is pretty straight. Why is the author considering `hash(pw, salt)` bad. The referenced question doesn't answer that.

Comment: Because `sha512` calculations are very fast. Have you read the references section of that wiki page? It's all there.

Comment: Treat passwords as a one way street. They only go to your machine and not the other way.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I've read the references and now the speed concert for brutefore hit me. Could you post your comment as an Answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago it was usual to hash passwords like this for saving in a database, for example:

```
$hashedPassword = MD5($password . $salt);
```

Hardware became faster, and the known fast hash functions like MD5, SHA-1, but also SHA-512 could be brute-forced much too fast. Nowadays [2012] it is possible to calculate about [8 Giga MD5 values](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) with common hardware, to brute-force a whole english dictionary with 500'000 words, you need only a fraction of a millisecond!

That's why key-derivation functions like BCrypt and PBKDF2 where invented. They have a cost parameter and repeat the hashing many times (the cost factor determines the number of iterations). **Each iteration will use the original salt** to calculate a new hash-value, that's why you have to pass the salt separately to the function and cannot concatenate it before:

```
$hashedPassword = Bcrypt($password, $salt);
```

The linked article either wants to explain that a single hash calculation is not sufficient nowadays, or it want's to show that the salt cannot be concatenated with the password before passing it to the hash function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should had replaced `+` with `,`. Anyway, how would your answer change if the hash function was `sha512`. Why is it considered not secure enough ?

Comment: @Alex - Rewrote the answer for future readers.